# how to fix 'HTTP Status 404 - /knowage/' error after installation Knowage with tomcat server(The requested resource is not available.)

Tags: tomcat, server, installation, fiware-knowage

I have installed knowage 6.4 in windows 7 successfully and after completing the installation when I tried to access it on 'http://localhost:8080/knowage', I am getting this error below
Error: HTTP Status 404 - /knowage/
Error Description: The requested resource is not available.
Could you please help?
Note, I did not use any external database instead I have used embedded maria Db when installing knowage

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your database is empty and there is no users registered. You should be able to see it the SBI_USER table, check the KNOWAGE_DEMO database.